# Python Program won't restart

Tags: python

I am trying to restart my program in python, but, for some reason, the code is getting caught up in the while playagain loop. It says "That was not a valid answer. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'." when I enter yes, no, or any of the other inputs that are acceptable. Why won't this work?

```
while True:
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again?")
    while playagain != "y" or playagain != "Y" or playagain != "Yes" or playagain != "yes" or playagain != "YES" or playagain != "n" or playagain != "N" or playagain != "No" or playagain != "no" or playagain != "NO":
         print("That was not a valid answer. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
         playagain = input("Would you like to play again?")
    if playagain == "y" or playagain == "Y" or playagain == "Yes" or playagain == "yes" or playagain == "YES":
         break
    else:
         print("Thank you for playing MadLibs!")
```

Comment: The negation of `a or b` is `(not a) and (not b)`.

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions.  If your question is closed, edit it to make it worth reopening.

Comment: Reopening this. Originally, OP had asked a different version of the question that **had a different problem**, and it was closed as a duplicate as appropriate. OP then tried to edit the question to show that the supposed fix still resulted in non-working code. Finally, this question is a duplicate **of the edited code**, but the code in the other question **should not have been edited like that** in the first place, because it makes a completely different question. I.e., this one. Which is therefore **not** a duplicate.

Comment: After reading the answers (and looking more closely at the code), I determined that the problem that was surfaced here is in fact **also** a common duplicate - of a different question. So I have used that instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lower()` function and the `in` operator to clean up the code.

You would change this code:

```
playagain = input("Would you like to play again?").lower()
while playagain not in ['y', 'yes', 'n', 'no']:
     print("That was not a valid answer. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
     playagain = input("Would you like to play again?").lower()
```

So that the whole code would be:

```
while True:
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again?").lower()
    while playagain not in ['y', 'yes', 'n', 'no']:
         print("That was not a valid answer. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
         playagain = input("Would you like to play again?").lower()
    if playagain in ['n', 'no']:
         print("Thank you for playing MadLibs!")
         break
```

Comment: I might even be lazier and say `input(...).lower().startswith('y')`

Comment: Ok, I did a version of this and it helped, but now instead of starting over when someone says yes and ending when someone says no, the message thank you for playing is printed and then the program starts over when you say yes and no

Comment: i think it has something to do with this part of the code :    if playagain.lower() in ['y', 'yes']:
        break
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing MadLibs!")

Comment: @xnathanmeyerx, try the whole code from the answer.

Comment: ok, that worked, but why didnt the one that i just put above work? it looks the same to me except you used no instead of yes and you got rid of the else

Comment: @xnathanmeyerx, you should break when the users says no. But your main problem is using `or` instead of `and`.

Comment: @xnathanmeyerx take a look at my answer - it addresses your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
while playagain != "y" or playagain != "Y" or playagain != "Yes"
```

to be:

```
while playagain != "y" and playagain != "Y" and playagain != "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this:

```
while True:
    valid_response = ["y","Yes","Y","No","n","N"]
    positive_response = ["y","Yes","Y"]
    playagain = input("Would you like to play again?")
    while playagain not in valid_response:
        print("That was not a valid answer. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
        playagain = input("Would you like to play again?")
    if playagain in positive_response:
        printf("You chose to play again"):
        break
    else:
        print("Thank you for playing MadLibs!")
        break;
```

The problem in your code is that at least one of ther statements in your while loop be true always. Because `playagain` can not be equal to `"Y"`, `"y"`, `"Yes"`, `"No"`, `"n"` and `"N"` at the same time (For the condition in loop to be false).